# would sending a const to a function that gets a non const param be considered an error?

Tags: c++, constants

let's say we have this function

```
void  something(int a)
{}
```

and in main function we do this

```
int main()
{
 const int a=7;
something(a);
}
```

would that be considered an error?

Comment: Remember that the argument is passed by *value*. Which means the value if the `main` variable `a` is *copied* into the `something` argument variable `a`. So in short, what you show is fine and will not lead to any errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay , and if it was passed by reference would that be different?

Comment: Yes, it is an error. If a function wants a non const type is because it wants to change the value. If you pass a const, you can't change it.

Comment: A non-const reference can't be bound to a const variable. So yes then it should lead to a build error.

Comment: .... taking in count what's been said, the question will be, do you want to modify `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

When you call the function, a copy of the parameter is made:

```
 const int x = 0;
 something(x);
```

It is similar to

```
 const int x = 0;
 int y = x;          // completely fine, no error
```

---

Further, consider that when you pass by value, using `const` on the argument only matters inside the function:

```
void  something(const int a)
{
    a = 42; // error, a is const
}
```

Though the type of the function is actually `void(int)`, ie the `const` on the argument is an implementation detail.

---

It does matter when you pass by reference:

```
 void foo(int& x); // <- modifies parameter

 const int x;
 foo(x);           // error, because x cannot be modified
```